# jQuery .find() and .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a thermometer and i am working on the animation of the thermometer. I have this javascript method for doing that:

```
function setScoreBar(score) {
    var scoreBar = document.getElementById("dynamicScoreBar");
    // var scoreBar = $(scoreBarElem);
    var height = 250;
    height = height - 20;
    var percentage = height / 100;
    scoreBar.find(".meter").animate({
         marginTop: (height - (score * percentage)) + "px"
    }, 400, function() {
        scoreBar.find(".meter").html(score + "%");
    });
}
```

and my html looks like this

```
<div id="dynamicScoreBar" class="scoreBar">
    <div class="meter">0%</div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

When i debugg it i get error that says that the .find and .animate methods don't exists. But when i try to write it i get help from visual studios and it shows me the option to use it so it should exist :P can i use something else? or do i have any syntax wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.find` and `.animate` are jQuery functions. They exist when `scoreBar` is a jQuery object. It is not when you assign it with `document.getElementById`. `getElementById` is a pure javascript function and will return a DOM node.

If you're using the jQuery framework, you can turn any DOM node into a jQuery object by wrapping it with `$(...)`. For your specific scenario, you could rewrite the variable assignment completely:

```
var scoreBar = $('#dynamicScoreBar');
```

... and the `scoreBar` variable will be a jQuery object with the `find` and `animate` functions available.

Comment: Perfect! Good explaining to! Thanks David!:)